# add code to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I execute the following code by clicking on an image?

```
$('#container').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
$(this).text('new text');
}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
```

Comment: By wrapping it in `$(image).on('click', function () {` perhaps

Answer (score 6):

```
$('yourimageselector').click(function () {
  $('#container').animate({
      'opacity': 0
  }, 1000, function () {
      $(this).text('new text');
  }).animate({
      'opacity': 1
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I just figured it out and came back to answer it myself but you beat me to it. I know it was a simple question but I'm learning and really appreciate you taking the time out!

Comment: @Chrismo16 Please take some time to try it before asking since it's the best way to improve yourself

Comment: Agreed. I have a few issues I have been trying to address in a very short time and my brain is on information overload.